# C++ struct doesn't align correctly to a pixel shader cbuffer

Tags: directx11, hlsl, memory-efficiency, c++

To expand from my [previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105518/mapping-a-c-struct-to-an-hlsl-cbuffer), I must add I can't correctly map my C++ structs to a corresponding `cbuffer` inside the **pixel shader**. When outputing random colors defined in the struct C++ side, it happens I get wrong results i.e. an `XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1.0)` would give me a red color (?).

So here is a code sample :

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct SceneParams {
    bool DEAOEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 DEAOColor;
    double DEAOPow;
    bool lightEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 lightColor;
    XMFLOAT3 lightDirection;
    bool lightMultiply;
    double lightMultiplyFactor;
    bool ambiantLightEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 ambiantLightColor;
    bool HSEnabled;
    int HSSpread;
    bool fogEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 fogColor;
    double fogDistanceMax;
    bool glowEnabled;
    XMFLOAT4 glowColor;
    double glowRadius;
    XMFLOAT4 skyColor;
    bool skyBoxEnabled;
    //uniform sampler2D skyBoxTexture;
    int skyBoxScheme0; // top
    int skyBoxScheme1; // left
    int skyBoxScheme2; // front
    int skyBoxScheme3; // right
    int skyBoxScheme4; // back
    int skyBoxScheme5; // bottom
    int skyBoxRotate;
    double skyBoxRotateSpeed;
    XMFLOAT3 skyBoxRotateAround;
    bool orbitTrapsEnabled;
    int orbitTrapsId;
    XMFLOAT4 objectColor;

    SceneParams(
        bool DEAOEnabled,
        XMFLOAT4 DEAOColor,
        double DEAOPow,
        bool lightEnabled,
        XMFLOAT4 lightColor,
        XMFLOAT3 lightDirection,
        bool lightMultiply,
        double lightMultiplyFactor,
        bool ambiantLightEnabled,
        XMFLOAT4 ambiantLightColor,
        bool HSEnabled,
        int HSSpread,
        bool fogEnabled,
        XMFLOAT4 fogColor,
        double fogDistanceMax,
        bool glowEnabled,
        XMFLOAT4 glowColor,
        double glowRadius,
        XMFLOAT4 skyColor,
        bool skyBoxEnabled,
        //uniform sampler2D skyBoxTexture,
        int skyBoxScheme0, // top
        int skyBoxScheme1, // left
        int skyBoxScheme2, // front
        int skyBoxScheme3, // right
        int skyBoxScheme4, // back
        int skyBoxScheme5, // bottom
        int skyBoxRotate,
        double skyBoxRotateSpeed,
        XMFLOAT3 skyBoxRotateAround,
        bool orbitTrapsEnabled,
        int orbitTrapsId,
        XMFLOAT4 objectColor
        ) : DEAOEnabled{ DEAOEnabled }, DEAOColor{ DEAOColor }, DEAOPow{ DEAOPow }, lightEnabled{ lightEnabled }, lightColor{ lightColor }, lightDirection{ lightDirection },
        lightMultiply{ lightMultiply }, lightMultiplyFactor{ lightMultiplyFactor }, ambiantLightEnabled{ ambiantLightEnabled }, ambiantLightColor{ ambiantLightColor },
        HSEnabled{ HSEnabled }, HSSpread{ HSSpread }, fogEnabled{ fogEnabled }, fogColor{ fogColor }, fogDistanceMax{ fogDistanceMax }, glowEnabled{ glowEnabled },
        glowColor{ glowColor }, glowRadius{ glowRadius }, skyColor{ skyColor }, skyBoxEnabled{ skyBoxEnabled }, skyBoxScheme0{ skyBoxScheme0 },
        skyBoxScheme1{ skyBoxScheme1 }, skyBoxScheme2{ skyBoxScheme2 }, skyBoxScheme3{ skyBoxScheme3 }, skyBoxScheme4{ skyBoxScheme4 }, skyBoxScheme5{ skyBoxScheme5 },
        skyBoxRotate{ skyBoxRotate }, skyBoxRotateSpeed{ skyBoxRotateSpeed }, skyBoxRotateAround{ skyBoxRotateAround }, orbitTrapsEnabled{ orbitTrapsEnabled },
        orbitTrapsId{ orbitTrapsId }, objectColor{ objectColor } {}

    SceneParams() {}
};

...
// create a scene params object
...

constantBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(SceneParams);
hr = g_d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&constantBufferDesc, nullptr, &g_d3dConstantBuffers[CB_Scene_Params]);
g_d3dDeviceContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(4, 1, &g_d3dConstantBuffers[CB_Scene_Params]);
g_d3dDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource(g_d3dConstantBuffers[CB_Scene_Params], 0, nullptr, &g_SceneParams, 0, 0);
```

With HLSL :

```
cbuffer sceneParams : register(b4) {
    bool DEAOEnabled;
    float4 DEAOColor;
    double DEAOPow;
    bool lightEnabled;
    float4 lightColor;
    float3 lightDirection;
    bool lightMultiply;
    double lightMultiplyFactor;
    bool ambiantLightEnabled;
    float4 ambiantLightColor;
    bool HSEnabled;
    int HSSpread;
    bool fogEnabled;
    float4 fogColor;
    double fogDistanceMax;
    bool glowEnabled;
    float4 glowColor;
    double glowRadius;
    float4 skyColor;
    bool skyBoxEnabled;
    //uniform sampler2D skyBoxTexture;
    int skyBoxScheme0; // top
    int skyBoxScheme1; // left
    int skyBoxScheme2; // front
    int skyBoxScheme3; // right
    int skyBoxScheme4; // back
    int skyBoxScheme5; // bottom
    int skyBoxRotate;
    double skyBoxRotateSpeed;
    float3 skyBoxRotateAround;
    bool orbitTrapsEnabled;
    int orbitTrapsId;
    float4 objectColor;
}
```

I changed my `cbuffer` `float`s to `double`s to match the C++ struct but to no avail. What's wrong with the way I did the mapping ?

---

Additionnaly, here is a byte-size dump of the struct members :

```
std::cout << sizeof(p.DEAOEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.DEAOColor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.DEAOPow) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.lightEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.lightColor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.lightDirection) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.lightMultiply) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.lightMultiplyFactor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.ambiantLightEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.ambiantLightColor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.HSEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.HSSpread) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.fogEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.fogColor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.fogDistanceMax) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.glowEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.glowColor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.glowRadius) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyColor) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxScheme[0]) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxScheme[1]) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxScheme[2]) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxScheme[3]) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxScheme[4]) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxScheme[5]) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxRotate) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxRotateSpeed) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.skyBoxRotateAround) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.orbitTrapsEnabled) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.orbitTrapsId) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(p.objectColor) << std::endl;
```

Which outputs :

```
1
16
8
1
16
12
1
8
1
16
1
4
1
16
8
1
16
8
16
1
4
4
4
4
4
4
1
8
12
1
4
16
```

Here is the compiler layout :

```
1>      +---
1>   0  | DEAOEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>   4  | XMFLOAT4 DEAOColor
1>      | <alignment member> (size=4)
1>  24  | DEAOPow
1>  32  | lightEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  36  | XMFLOAT4 lightColor
1>  52  | XMFLOAT3 lightDirection
1>  64  | lightMultiply
1>      | <alignment member> (size=7)
1>  72  | lightMultiplyFactor
1>  80  | ambiantLightEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  84  | XMFLOAT4 ambiantLightColor
1>  100 | HSEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  104 | HSSpread
1>  108 | fogEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  112 | XMFLOAT4 fogColor
1>  128 | fogDistanceMax
1>  136 | glowEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  140 | XMFLOAT4 glowColor
1>      | <alignment member> (size=4)
1>  160 | glowRadius
1>  168 | XMFLOAT4 skyColor
1>  184 | skyBoxEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  188 | skyBoxScheme0
1>  192 | skyBoxScheme1
1>  196 | skyBoxScheme2
1>  200 | skyBoxScheme3
1>  204 | skyBoxScheme4
1>  208 | skyBoxScheme5
1>  212 | skyBoxRotate
1>  216 | skyBoxRotateSpeed
1>  224 | XMFLOAT3 skyBoxRotateAround
1>  236 | orbitTrapsEnabled
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>  240 | orbitTrapsId
1>  244 | XMFLOAT4 objectColor
1>      | <alignment member> (size=4)
1>      +---
```

Comment: You may find `/d1reportSingleClassLayout<name>` a useful command-line switch if using VS. You can add it to your project options via the "Additional Compiler Options" section of the C++ properties of your project. Replace "<name>" with a type name (e.g., /d1reportSingleClassLayoutSceneParams) and compile; the compiler's interpretation of the class layout will be printed to the output window, including pad bytes.

Comment: I can't find this option (VS 2015 community). -all right it's under Command Line ...

Comment: It's "undocumented."

Comment: I passed a `**ptrptr` instead of `*ptr` to my `UpdateSubresource()` for `pSrcData` :/ Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-array struct members for constant buffers in HLSL are packed on four byte offsets, as many as it can into 16-byte vectors. If a member would straddle a vector boundary, it starts a new vector.

You cannot achieve this with just an alignment and pack directive, you need to have explicit padding in your CPU-side structure to emulate the [CB layout rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Laying your structure out by hand:

```
Legend:
[--]             4 bytes, bool/short/int/float
[------]         8 bytes, double/float2
[----------]     12 bytes, float3
[--------------] 16 bytes, float4, double2

0123456789abcdef
[--]             *- bool DEAOEnabled;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 DEAOColor;
[------][--]     *- double DEAOPow;
                 \- bool lightEnabled;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 lightColor;
[----------][--] *- XMFLOAT3 lightDirection;
                 \- bool lightMultiply;
[------][--]     *- double lightMultiplyFactor;
                 \- bool ambiantLightEnabled;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 ambiantLightColor;
[--][--][--]     *- bool HSEnabled;
                 |- int HSSpread;
                 \- bool fogEnabled;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 fogColor;
[------][--]     *- double fogDistanceMax;
                 \- bool glowEnabled;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 glowColor;
[------]         *- double glowRadius;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 skyColor;
[--][--][--][--] *- bool skyBoxEnabled;
                 |- int skyBoxScheme0; // top
                 |- int skyBoxScheme1; // left
                 \- int skyBoxScheme2; // front
[--][--][--][--] *- int skyBoxScheme3; // right
                 |- int skyBoxScheme4; // back
                 |- int skyBoxScheme5; // bottom
                 \- int skyBoxRotate;
[------]         *- double skyBoxRotateSpeed;
[----------][--] *- XMFLOAT3 skyBoxRotateAround;
                 \- bool orbitTrapsEnabled;
[--]             *- int orbitTrapsId;
[--------------] *- XMFLOAT4 objectColor;
```

We can see here that you have a lot of gaps in the canonical CB layout due to would-be straddling elements which you need to emulate on the CPU side.

Comment: Terrific answer =D Thanks a lot. So as an example, if I am @ position `skyBoxRotateAround` inside the cbuffer, defining `float4 skyBoxRotateAround` would give me the `orbitTrapsEnabled` value as `skyBoxRotateAround.w` ? I wonder why DX11 doesn't have an OpenGL `glGetUniformLocation()` similar methodology ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle In the original buffer definition, `skyBoxRotateAround` lives in `cb[16].xyz` and `orbitTrapsEnabled` would reside in `cb[16].w`. As the types differ and constant buffer contents go through no value translation, mapping in a float4 would result in a rather meaningless `.w` swizzle.

Comment: Is `cb[x]` a valid syntax ? I guess not would be cool tho :|

Answer (score 0):

I believe your DEAOColor crosses the 16 byte alignment boundary. Your first bool is 4 bytes so DEAOColor get's cut in two. Try switching them (and any other variable that doesn't fit within the 16 byte steps).

Comment: I thought `__declspec(align(16))` would take care of that ?

Comment: I'm unsure but I don't think you can count on that when sending to video memory. You might need a padding variable as well, so the entire structure is a multiple of 16.

Comment: The c++ structure is definitely a multiple of 16 - else the rendering would crash and the console output some complaining (happened to me before - `D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer: The Dimensions are invalid. For ConstantBuffers, marked with the D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER BindFlag, the ByteWidth (value = xxx) must be a multiple of 16. [...]`).